# How to best implement an OGC best practice

Tags: geoserver, ogc

I'm having some difficulty wrapping my head around building an OGC compliant Earth Observation ordering service. I'm not asking for a step by step process but rather hope to spawn a high level discussion about what might be the best way to approach this task.

There is this best practice document on what i would like to accomplish:
[Order Services for Earth Observation Products OGC 06-141r2](http://services.eoportal.org/portal/documents/06-141r2_Ordering_Services_for_Earth_Observation_Products_0.9.2.pdf)

However, i'm not sure whether i should get the schema(xsd) files that are at the bottom of the PDF and generate stubs from them, or leverage geoNetwork in some way. I have no idea where to start. Has anyone any experience implementing any OGC standards, best practices or something similar? Where do i start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest contacting the editor directly. I believe that there are reference implementations that you can take a look at. The editor is Daniele Marchionni .

Cheers

Comment: I was able to contact him finally.

Comment: It's been awhile, but would you like to share your experience?